# Fedora upgrade stuck between version 16 and 20

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I was given remote ssh access to a server running Fedora 16. I tried upgrading it to Fedora 20 and rebooted. But it looks like the system wasn't fully updated.

```
# uname -a 
Linux garden 3.1.0-7.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 21:10:48 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
```

As you see I have an old kernel, but a new Fedora release.

How do I bring the entire system up to version 20? I don't have physical access to the server, only ssh access.

It seems I don't have any Fedora 20 kernels installed

```
# rpm -qa |grep ^kernel
kernel-devel-3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64
kernel-3.3.1-3.fc16.x86_64
kernel-3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64
kernel-3.1.0-7.fc16.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.1.0-7.fc16.x86_64
```

I can't remember exactly what steps I took when performing the upgrade, or in what order. But something along the lines of

```
# yum update yum
# yum clean all
# rpm -Uhv http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-20-1.noarch.rpm
# rpm -Uhv http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/f/fedora-release-notes-20-0.5.noarch.rpm
# rpm --import https://getfedora.org/static/246110C1.txt
# yum groupupdate Base
# yum grouplist
# yum groupupdate 'Minimal Install'
# /usr/sbin/grub2-install /dev/sda
# cp --backup=numbered -a /boot/grub2/grub.cfg{,.bak}
# /usr/sbin/grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
# cd /etc/rc.d/init.d; for f in *; do [ -x $f ] && /sbin/chkconfig $f resetpriorities; done
# package-cleanup --orphans
```

And then finally

```
# shutdown -r now
```

And that's where I am now.

Comment: If you run `rpm -qa |grep ^kernel`, you can see any `kernel-<version>.fc20.x86_64` package installed?. If the answer is YES, is just a matter of changing grub configuration of the default kernel to a `fc20` one, or removing the old kernels(`fc16`) using yum.

Comment: Nope, only fc16 kernels. See my updated question :)

Comment: Did you upgrade *directly* from 16 -> 20?  I don't think that is intended to happen.  But of course, **you don't describe your methodology at all**, making this harder to diagnose...

Comment: Yes, I did. And yes, I've come to the same conclusion :) I intentionally left out the steps I took, because I can't remember them exactly. I should have written them down as I performed them, but alas, I didn't. Nevertheless I've added what I can remember to the question.

Comment: What about if you use the recommended tool to make the upgrade? - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp | https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading - `fedup --network 20 --product=[workstation | server| cloud | nonproduct]`. It seems that this manual process that you've made is a little "risky"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion is. Don't do this!

I managed to get physical access to the machine and installed from a bootable USB.